# iPad Air 2 restored now i need to activate it

Tags: ipad

I had restored my iPad Air 2 but now it says I need to activate it with the Apple ID used to set it up but I have forgotten my ID and password. The only way I can use it is to use the previous Apple ID and password. Is there any way I can change the Apple ID to a different new account?

Answer (score 0):

> I have forgotten my ID and password

We are well into the 21st century - your ID and password are as essential to modern life as your date of birth and Social Insurance Number. "I forgot my ____" is no longer acceptable.

If you are the original purchaser of the iPad, go to any Apple store with the device and the receipt. They can remove the activation locks. If you did not set it up originally, contact the person who did. If that isn't possible, go to any retailer with your credit card and get a new one.